# Different methods for requesting data from server with authentication

Tags: php, javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

If I am interested in creating a web application that fetches user data from a server with authentication (using the Google Picasa API to get private Picasa web albums, for example), what are the different languages and methods I would use to accomplish this? Is it possible with Javascript? To start, I know this:

PHP: the cURL library

Any resources online that might give a better idea of the concepts behind this are welcome as well!

Comment: No it is not possible with Javascript alone. You need a server side language as well like PHP or ASP.NET. Have you tried reading the Google code documentation available for this? - http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/code.html

Comment: That's the documentation that I needed! Not sure why I hadn't found it before, thanks very much.

Comment: Since this documentation for PHP, Python, etc is listed under "Version 1.0," do you by any chance have an idea if there were any significant changes to the protocol with Version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/developers-guide.html, section "Versions of the protocol"